# Nvidia Driver 440 on GTX1050M recognizing Laptop Screen during but not after boot, only Second Monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, laptop, nvidia-geforce

Basically the title, Using nouveau drivers both the laptop screen and monitor works fine. Wanted to do some nvenc stuff so I got the nvidia drivers via the additional drivers app in 20.04. With any of the ones ubuntu suggested (440, 435, 390) the laptop boots using the laptop screen (displaying grub information, ubuntu logo, and starting services) but when the boot process finishes only the secondary screen works. I have also tried switching nomodeset to quiet splash in the grub settings but there is no change. If I change the gpu in nvidia x server settings to the intel integrated one, the laptop screen works fine but then I cannot use the gpu. Any advice would be appreciated. The laptop is a dell inspiron 15 i7567. Also if I switch to a different tty using ctrl-alt-f3 the console is on the laptop screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: Install the new 450 driver

Long story long: Use "Additional drivers" to install nouveau drivers, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`, reboot, repeat until boots on laptop screen, run `sudo Xorg :1 -configure` to generate xorg.conf.new file, copy that somewhere else just in case, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`, reboot, go into tty2 using ctrl-alt-f2 because you can't get past the login screen, run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the newest 450 drivers, reboot, pray, have it all work.

I don't know which part fixed it and which parts did nothing but that is everything I ran that eventually got it working.

Also below is the new xorg.conf that NVIDIA X Server Settings created that you may be able to modify slightly and place in /etc/X11/xorg.conf to get yours working:

Edit: I could not get this file working when fractional scaling broke my config again and repeating this steps would not fix it. I think the key was whatever caused my tty2 to not load into the gui.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 3840 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "TOSHIBA-TV"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 68.0
    VertRefresh     23.0 - 61.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName      "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier     "Card0"
    Driver         "intel"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"

        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
    Identifier     "Card1"
    Driver         "nouveau"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +3840+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Card1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection     "Display"
        Viewport    0 0
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Did you install " third party software " in OS installation ?

You can try to delete your not working graphics, but more easy is a fresh new OS installation and let system choose right drivers. Install via `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` won't enough to completely purge files and paths. Nothing other works for me.

[image]

Comment: I did do that at startup. Can't do a full reset right now so I was hoping there was another solution.

Comment: I don't know any other solutions. But surely existing.